# `pthread_mutex_trylock` blocks when called by two threads at the same time

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, pthreads, mutex

I'm using `pthread_mutex_trylock` to lock the mutex on a struct so that it can only be accessed/modified by a single thread at a given time. If the mutex is already locked I just return from the routine rather than queuing/blocking.

This is a basic outline of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t m;
} myStruct;

void setupStruct(myStruct* struc) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&struc->m, NULL);
}

void structOp(myStruct* struc) {

    printf("structOp(): Trying to lock\n");

    if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&struc->m) != 0) {
        printf("structOp(): Lock failed\n");
        return;
    } else {
        printf("structOp(): Locked\n");
        // do some stuff to struct
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&struc->m);
    }
}
```

The struct is initialised once like this:

```
myStruct* struc = malloc(sizeof(struc));
setupStruct(struc);
```

However, sometimes when two threads call a routine at the same time both calls to `trylock` seem to block. I'm assuming this because it prints "Trying to lock" for both threads at the same time, but does not print whether or not the mutex was locked. I was originally having this problem with `pthread_mutex_lock` so tried the non-blocking version for this reason, but it still seems to block.

This doesn't always happen but when it does it's always the **first two** calls to the routine. If the first two calls run fine, then subsequent calls also work fine.

Is there any reason this would block? Am I just incorrectly perceiving this blocking due to some other problem? I can post other parts of my code if the problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: There is no reason for this to block, AFAIK. Something's probably wrong elsewhere.

Comment: What calls setupStruct()?  It's not called more than once, by any chance?

Comment: It's definitely only called once, just before the new threads are started. I think if there's a problem it's most likely with my use of pointers. Do these seem correct? I'm allocating the struct with `myStruct* struc = malloc(sizeof(struc));`. I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: myStruct* struc = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));  /// not struc - struc is a pointer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    myStruct* struc = malloc(sizeof(struc));
```

It does not alloate enough memory, so you're probably trashing/reusing the memory where you access mutex. Using `sizeof(struc)` allocates memory for the type of `struc` , and the type of `struc` is a `myStruct*` , so you're only allocating memory enough to hold a pointer (i.e.likely just 4 or 8 bytes)

You should do

```
    myStruct* struc = malloc(sizeof *struc);
```

or

```
    myStruct* struc = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
```

Comment: Wow, I've been allocating my structs wrong for a long time.. thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of timing issue or memory corruption. Either way it's not related to the code you posted, so there's no way to answer this question.

If your OS supports valgrind, check your app with the [memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) and [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) modules.